# Post relational data, Spring JPA REST

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I have a relational database with a normalized form of my data, but my API will need to receive the information in a denormalized way, what is the correct way to handle this? Is it a matter of creating a new endpoint with the fields denormalized?

How would I decouple that from the database so that Spring Boot doesn't create a new table for me?

For example, here are (some of) my tables:

```
@Entity
public class TestCase {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}

@Entity
public class TestRun {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;    
    private Boolean result;
    private String username;
    @OneToOne 
    private TestData testData;
    @ManyToOne 
    private TestCase testCase;
 }

@Entity
public class TestData {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private int count;
    @ManyToOne 
    private RecordType recordType;
}
```

I want to create an API endpoint that will create new entries in TestRun and TestData at the same time, while referencing existing entries in TestCase and RecordType.

How is this done?

A complete answer needs to show:

- What format the data would take when its posted to the server
- What component will handle that post
- How that component will update the different Entities

Comment: what do you mean with denormalized?

Comment: When I send the data to my API I want to send all the fields shown above as a single request. But I want that request to get broken up and put into the right tables.

Comment: you can send a unique request with the 2 objects and the request will read them as 2 objects, then you can process them as you wish and save first one into one table and later other or whatever you need. Also if you add cascadeType=PERSIST into your relationships saving only the parent object, all relations will be stored

Comment: The way I understand it, each object has its own API endpoint, so how would I send multiple different objects to one endpoint?

Alternatively I could send multiple requests, but I'm not sure how that would work. If I post to /TestData, how do I indicate that I want it to link with a specific TestRun id number (that I just created)?

Comment: Lets imagine, you want to create an object of type TestData, then you create an URL /testData (POST) and in that request you will receive an object of type TestData, this object have a relation with RecordType, so you can say in your TestData object, that when you persist, update, remove...the main object TestData, you want to add actions in cascade, you should add to your TestData class:  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) then the object will be create in only one request action

Comment: I'm interested in how that would be represented in the JSON. Because it can't assume which RecordType to link to just from the fields of TestData.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127052/discussion-between-cralfaro-and-clickcell).

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})` to all the `@OneToOne` and  `@ManyToOne`  relationship when you persist a TestRun object all the existing object should be persisted also.

```
 public class TestRun {
    @Id 
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name="id", columnDefinition = "numeric")
            private Long id;  //Long so default value is null
            @Column(name="result", columnDefinition ="nchar")
            private Boolean result;
            @Column(name="username")
            private String username;

            @OneToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="id_data")
            @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
            private TestData testData;

            @OneToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="id_case")
            @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
            private TestCase testCase;
}
```

Input:
`{
    "result" : "true",
    "username" : "clickcell",
    "testData" : {
        "count" : "10"
    },
    "testCase" : {
        "name" : "test1",
        "description" : "the first test"
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on how I will be able to post the data to the API? Will I be able to send all the data in a single POST and can I reference the existing records by their ID numbers? For example I want to say I have a new test run that passed (test case id6), which created 5 records of test data (record type id4).

Comment: You will be able to send all the data in one single post. The object that is send in the post has to match the fields structure from TestRun. If there are ids the entity manager will update the existing rows in the database and insert the ones that don't have an id.

Comment: The question is how. Let's say I send `{ "result" : "true", "username" : "clickcell", "testData" : { "count" : "10", "recordType" : "4" }, "testCase" : {"name" : "test1", "description" : "the first test"} }`

It doesn't work because it creates the testData object as a blank. Do you see what I am asking now?

Comment: I spor the problem: the id of the entities should be Long so that the default value to be null, otherwise the value will be ) and will not update or save the new row. Other than that you json should be correct.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean now, change the lowercase long to uppercase Long. I have tried this but the behavior doesn't seem to have changed for me. Nothing is getting added to testData

Comment: I tested the code and the data got into the database. How do you persist the testRun entity?

Comment: I have a ManyToOne from TestRun to TestCase, not OneToOne like in your example, although I tried changing it and it didn't fix my problem. I don't understand your question. I don't have any extra code to persist the data, just what is built into Spring Boot.

Comment: You need to have some method of save into database that opens a transaction, inserts the data and then close the transaction so that the data persist. Depending on what entity manager you use is possible this to be implicit. Does any details saved in the database? The object matched in the rest controller is correctly populated (do you see the id as null value) ?

Comment: After posting the data my database looks like this:

    `select * from test_run;
    ID,RESULT,TEST_CASE_ID,TEST_DATA_ID,USERNAME  
    1,TRUE,null,null,clickcell
    (4 rows, 0 ms)
    
    select * from test_case
    ID,DESCRIPTION,NAME,(no rows, 0 ms)
    
    select * from test_data
    ID,COUNT,RECORD_TYPE_ID,(no rows, 0 ms)` It saves only result and username.

Comment: Did you added the @JoinColumn in the TestRun entity as I mentioned in my example?